# Webcam-based behavior analysis of users reading a MS Word file

Tags: webcam, reading, computer-vision, research

I am looking for a free software application to analyze reading behavior (where do they more stop while reading, etc.) of the readers of MS Word files. I guess such program would probably use an eye tracking system. What's more, I need to do that with a webcam.